# GoogleMaps React: Open InfoWindow by Default - not from onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-react

I would like to have an info window open by default above a marker in a google maps component in my react project.

I have tried to accomplish this by having a ref for the marker component, the handler for which calls the marker onclick method which triggers the info window toggle.

However, I am finding that state is not updating despite my call to setState. I have tried doing this in componentDidMount and have also tried setting state directly in the marker mounting handler.

State is mutated successfully if clicking on the marker manually.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216180/open-infowindows-by-default) solution but it is a little inelegant as far as using it within react goes and I am frustrated in that I don't see any problems with my logic. It should work and I'd like to know why it doesn't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - my code is below:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import {Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react';

const style = {
    height:'400px',
    width: '100%'
}

class MapView extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
        showingInfoWindow: true, 
        activeMarker: {},         
        selectedPlace: {}         
      };
    }

    onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
        selectedPlace: props,
        activeMarker: marker,
        showingInfoWindow: true
      }));
    }

    onMarkerMounted = element => this.onMarkerClick(element.props, element.marker, element);

    onClose = () => {
      if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
        this.setState({
          showingInfoWindow: false,
          activeMarker: null
        });
      }
    };

    render() {
        return(
            <Map
              google={this.props.google}
              style={style}
              initialCenter={{
                lat: {redacted},
                lng: {redacted}
              }}
              zoom={15}
              onClick={this.onMapClicked}
            >
                <Marker ref={this.onMarkerMounted} onClick={this.onMarkerClick}/>
                <InfoWindow
          marker={this.state.activeMarker}
          visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
          onClose={this.onClose}
        >
          <div>
            Your Location Here!
          </div>
        </InfoWindow>

            </Map>
        );
    }
} 

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: ('MY_API_KEY')
})(MapView);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe everything is fine with your example. It appears the reason why info window is not getting displayed is because the map is not yet fully loaded once `onMarkerMounted` function is triggered.

Here is the list of changes to display info window once the map is loaded:

a) introduce `mapLoaded` state to keep track whether map has been loaded or not:

```
this.state = {
  //...  
  mapLoaded: false
};
```

and set it to `true` once the map is loaded:

```
handleMapIdle = () => {
    this.setState({
      mapLoaded: true
    });
}


<Map
    google={this.props.google}
    style={style}
    initialCenter={this.props.center}
    zoom={this.props.zoom}
    onIdle={this.handleMapIdle}
  >
  ...
</Map>
```

and finally initialize marker once the map is loaded:

```
{this.state.mapLoaded && (
   <Marker ref={this.onMarkerMounted} onClick={this.onMarkerClick} />
)}
```

[Here is a **demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jzhrdy)

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. So the lesson here is component mounted !== component loaded. I'm sure this will become clearer to me as I learn the inner workings of react better.